# Debezium compatibility with Kafka version

Tags: apache-kafka, version, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Trying to connect to Kafka provisioned on cloud with help of Debezium docker image. Is Debezium compatible with all Kafka  versions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
include error message, include [example] of your code,
 provide more information about the problem: 
results, tools, resource links, screenshots, links
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Debezium should be compatible with all Kafka versions down to 0.10.1